# Как сделать ограниченное время хранения?

Tags: php

Есть задача: ограничить время хранения, ограничение выбирает сам пользователь.

Н-р: 2 инпута, в одно пишем число, а в другое выбираем из выпадающего списка тип хранения

2 | часа (минут, дней, неделя)

Задачу с хранением на несколько дней и недель сделал.

а вот как сделать 1 и 2-е? как сделать хранение на несколько часов/минут?

Вот как я сделал хранение дней

где

```
$row_c['load_date'] - время загрузки файла.
$current_d - нынешнее время.
$row_c['time_save'] - время хранения выбранное пользователем.
```

>

```
$count_date = $row_c['load_date'] - $current_d;

    $difference = intval(abs(strtotime($row_c['load_date']) - strtotime($current_d))); 

    // Количество дней 
      $finish_c_d = (int)$int_count_date = $difference / (3600 * 24);

      // Проверка и удаление
      // Проверка дней
      if ($finish_c_d > $row_c['time_save']) {
        echo "время истекло, данные удалились! id= ".$row_c['id'];
      }else{echo "Рано удалять! id= ".$row_c['id'];}

    }
```

Comment: когда создаете запись - пишите дату, когда надо удалять (т.е. высчитываете ее сразу), потом, когда будут обращаться к записи - проверяете доступна ли она или нет. И периодически запускаете крон для удаления старых данных. На `mysql` было бы так: для получения доступных - `select * from table_name where time_delete > now()`, для получения устаревших - `select * from table_name where time_delete <= now()`. Т.к. мы уже не работает с часами/минутами и т.д., а работаем с одним временем, то можно добавлять какой угодно промежуток (хоть 55 секунд, хоть два года и 10 дней). Как-то так.

Comment: да, если указывать точное время и дату то получается, просто пользователям немного неудобно что нужно выбирать дату, поэтому пришлось сделать так : 1 input в которое вводится число от 1 до 24 и 1 select из которого они выбирают тип хранения (минут, час, день) и вот после этого данные сохраняются, в итоге база выглядит так:
date_load | time_load | time_save | type_save
26.11.2015| 11.00.02 | 2 | часа
date_load и time_load - автоматически записываются после загрузки данных.
нужно как-то что-то сделать с time _load, time_save, type_save

Comment: нужно как то сделать чтобы она посмотрела сколько часов назад был загружен файл, потом посмотреть сколько часов его хранить, если time_load > time_save то удалять его.
Нужно time_save превратить в часы что ли 0_o
потому что time_load в таком формате 11:00:12 а time_save в таком 2 часа

Comment: а как к этому времени 11:00:12 прибавить 2 часа?
и так же к 11:00:12 прибавить 2 минуты?

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сделал

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = date($load_time);
                $time2=$row_c['time_save']." hours"; 

                $vychislenie_save_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($time2, strtotime($time)));
                $current_now_t = date('H:i:s', time());

                echo $vychislenie_save_time."--------".$row_c['id']."   <br>";
                echo $current_now_t."current time -------<br>";

                if ($current_now_t > $vychislenie_save_time) {
                    echo "время истекло, данные удалились! id= ".$row_c['id'];
                }else{echo "Рано удалять! id= ".$row_c['id'];}
```